# How can I use different variables to calculate a new variable, depending on which variable has missing values?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, na

I would like to create a variable `x` that is the product of variable `e` and one of the variables `a, b, c`, or `d`. The resulting variable should take the value `a * e`, but if `a` is `NA`, then it should take the value `b * e` and if `a & b` are missing, then it should take the value `c * e` and so on.

For example: If my data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 5), b = c(NA, 1, NA, 4, 6), c = c(NA, 3, 3, 3, 7), d = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), e = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA))
```

I would like to get to having the following result:

```
df$x <- c(1, 4, 9, 16, NA)
```

which I am trying to achieve the following way:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(x = case_when(!is.na(a) ~ a * e, is.na(a) ~ b * e, is.na(a) & is.na(b) ~ c * e, is.na(a) & is.na(b) & is.na(c) ~ d * e))
```

This, unfortunately is not working yet, since R is somehow not understanding `is.na(a) & is.na(b)` as both values missing at the same time.

Comment: your dataframe is incorrect. It has different lengths

Comment: Wouldn't the 3rd value of x be 3 * 3 = 9?

Comment: @dcarlos, also true, thank you for the comment!

Comment: For future reference: what happens when I use ```is.na(a) & is.na(b)```? Why does it not work the same way as ```a>1 & b>2```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` from `dplyr` to find the first non-missing element.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(x = e * coalesce(a, b, c, d))

#    a  b  c d  e  x
# 1  1 NA NA 1  1  1
# 2  2  1  3 1  2  4
# 3 NA NA  3 1  3  9
# 4 NA  4  3 1  4 16
# 5  5  6  7 1 NA NA
```

If you have lots of columns to be multiplied, you can automate it by using tidy-selection in `across()`. (Edit: Thank **@akrun** for the improvement)

```r
df %>%
  mutate(x = e * do.call(coalesce, across(a:d)))
```

Comment: Building on this approach: how can I then create a variable that tells me, which variable was used in the previous calculation?

Comment: @Anton Something like this: `df %>% mutate(x = do.call(coalesce, across(a:d, ~ replace(.x, !is.na(.x), cur_column()))))`

Answer (score 2):

```r
df <-
  data.frame(
    a = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 5),
    b = c(NA, 1, NA, 4, 6),
    c = c(NA, 3, 3, 3, 7),
    d = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    e = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA)
  )

df$res <- df[, 5] * apply(df[-5], 1, function(x) x[which(x = !is.na(x))[1]])
df
#>    a  b  c d  e res
#> 1  1 NA NA 1  1   1
#> 2  2  1  3 1  2   4
#> 3 NA NA  3 1  3   9
#> 4 NA  4  3 1  4  16
#> 5  5  6  7 1 NA  NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is there any chance to formulate this in a way, that only uses the variable names? My actual dataset contains many variables and I would like to code it in a way, that allows me to execute the code, irrespective of the position of the column but only calling the columns by name. Thank you!

Comment: Slight variation on @Yuriy Saraykin: `apply(df, 1, function(x) head(na.omit(x[c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")]), 1) * x["e"])`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `row/column` indexing

```
df$res <- df$e * df[-5][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
     max.col(!is.na(df[-5]), 'first'))]
df$res
[1]  1  4  9 16 NA
```